# Revolving text generator

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I am in the process of building a revolving text generator. The generator combines sentences (text) from a number of arrays, 'cycles' through them visually and appends them. I thought it best to create a Fiddle with a [basic version of the generator](http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/nS8Mr/) as I have constructed it now:

**Explanation**

The basic workings are as follows:

1. Sentences are defined in separate arrays (`Array1`, `Array2` and `Array3` in the fiddle)
2. A second set of arrays is defined, containing the arrays that can be combined (`combo0` and `combo1` in the fiddle)
3. On pressing the 'Generate' button, the function `Generate` is called, which visually cycles the sentences from an array of sentences (`combo0[0]` in the fiddle)
4. This function loops itself until the sentence has cycled 8 times (`var times = 8` in the fiddle)
5. When this is done, the function calls the callback function that was provided. In this callback, it runs `Generate` again, this time with the second array (`combo0[1]` in the fiddle)

The reason for the callback is that I need to 'wait' for the cycling effect to complete, and then move on.

**The issue**

While this does exactly what I need (and besides the fact that I'm highly doubtful if this is the way to do it; I always feel a bit odd when writing a function that loops itself), I have the following problem:

In the `combo` arrays, I define which of the 'sentence' arrays can be possible combinations. This works fine if there are **two combinations**, but with more than two, I have a problem:

```
Generate(combo0[0], i, function(i) { //generate from first array element of combo0, callback to generating from second array of combo0
    Generate(combo0[1], i, function(i) {
        $('div#status').html('Done!'); //show status
        $('input#generate').removeAttr("disabled"); //enable button
    });
})
```

I would have to recursively rewrite this to accommodate the possibility of a `combo` array consisting of 3 or even 4 options. And probably this will break the script if a `combo` array contains just 2 (or 1) arrays.

This is where I'm stuck. The main issue is that if I loop over the `combo` array, e.g. with an .each();, the `generate` function is called multiple times synchronously, so the whole 'cycling' effect is lost.

I have tried writing various loops, which take into account the array length of the given `combo` array, but I have crashed more browsers today than ever before, and I can't work out what to do.

Comment: So you need a script that can go through multiple arrays, one item at a time, until it reaches a certain item in the array, and then progress to the next array, and present each step visually?

Comment: Well, not a certain item; a random item from an array. It needs to print out an array item x times, then finally write one down and continue to the next array. Basically, everything that it needs to do is working in the Fiddle (see my post), except for an array containing more than 2 arrays.

Comment: _I thought it best to create a Fiddle_ - yep! +1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to fix it. Some time away from the screen is a good thing.

What I did is add an 'n' counter which increases if the multiple of the `times` variable is reached, causing the function to continue iteration, but outputting (see third-to-last line) from the next array (`lists[n]`). Finally, a check to see how much arrays are left will determine if we're done. If done, write the sentence one last time, run the optional callback and return false. This way, the function will accept the entire array, and not just the subarray (`combo` as opposed to `combo[0]`):

```
//Generate from array 'lists', simulating a 'slot machine
function Generate(lists, n, i, callbackFnk) {
    if (!(i >= 0)) { i= 0; }
    setTimeout((function(msg){
        i++;
        return function(){
            if (i % times != 0){
                //We haven't reached a multiple of the times variable yet, keep going.
                Generate(lists, n, i, callbackFnk);
            } else if (i % times === 0 && i != 0 && n < (lists.length-1)) {
                //Multiple reached, increase n
                n++;
                Generate(lists, n, i, callbackFnk);
            } else if (n == (lists.length-1)) {
                //we are done as there are no more arrays to go over
                showMessage(msg, i);
                if (callbackFnk) callbackFnk.call(this, i);
                return false;
            }
            showMessage(msg, i);
        }
    })(
        //output using the given n value
        lists[n][Math.floor(Math.random() * lists[n].length)]
    ), speed);
}
```

See the working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/c_kick/kuNrA/1/

I hope this helps others!

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var Array1 = new Array("Sentence 1 - A ", "Sentence 1 - B ", "Sentence 1 - C ", "Sentence 1 - D ", "Sentence 1 - E ", "Sentence 1 - F ", "Sentence 1 - G ");
var Array2 = new Array("Sentence 2 - A", "Sentence 2 - B", "Sentence 2 - C", "Sentence 2 - D", "Sentence 2 - E", "Sentence 2 - F", "Sentence 2 - G");
var Array3 = new Array("Sentence 3 - A", "Sentence 3 - B", "Sentence 3 - C", "Sentence 3 - D", "Sentence 3 - E", "Sentence 3 - F", "Sentence 3 - G");

//define acceptable combinations of arrays
var combo0 = new Array(Array1, Array2);
var combo1 = new Array(Array1, Array2, Array3);

//define global vars
var speed = 140;
var content = '';

//write sentence to box. If counter is a multiple of the 'times' var: append instead of write
function showMessage(list, i, e) {
    $('div#generated').html(content + list[i]);
    if ((i + 1) % (e + 1) == 0) content += list[i];
}

//Generate from array 'list', simulating a 'slot machine
function Generate(lists, end, l, i, e) {
    if (l == undefined) l = 0;
    if (i == undefined) i = 0;
    if (e == undefined) e = Math.floor(Math.random() * lists[l].length);
    setTimeout(function() {
        showMessage(lists[l], i, e);
        if ((i + 1) % (e + 1) != 0)
            Generate(lists, end, l, i+1, e);
        else if (lists.length - 1 > l)
            Generate(lists, end, l + 1);
        else end();
    }, speed);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input#generate').click(function() {
        $(this).attr("disabled", true); //disable button
        content = ''; //reset content
        $('div#status').html('Running..'); //show status
        Generate(combo0, function() {
            $('div#status').html('Done!'); //show status
            $('input#generate').removeAttr("disabled"); //enable button});
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Wow, this works, only it seems 'instable'; it doesn't 'cycle' steadily on each array (I noticed you dropped the 'times' variable). Sometimes the first array item will just show, the second will cycle 5 times, the third 2 times. I will have a look and figure out how you managed it and see if I can work it out. Thanks though!

Comment: Alas, I can't figure out how to fix it; I need it to be stable (always cycling a set amount for each array item). Thanks again for your suggestion though!

Comment: I've tried to investigate it by decreasing the speed to 1 tick per second (speed=1000), and i didn't see any regularities, it may simply be caused by too high a speed.

Comment: Well, I tried to do it at a high speed, check your code in this fiddle: (try several times) http://jsfiddle.net/qC2T6/. In the meanwhile I seem to have cracked it myself! Will post an answer to my own question in a few minutes.